# VxWorks porting(DM8168)

Tags: vxworks

I have Spectrum Digital evaluation board (evm816x). 
I have the problem, when i'm trying to port vxWorks 6.9 to the TMS320DM8168(davinci). 
I load u-boot to NAND, it starts, all okey.  Then, I load vxWorks image with xds510 usb emulator. All okey, vxWorks works good. Then, i'm trying to start vxWorks from u-boot, its crashing through initialization process.
After a few experiments I came to conclusion that vxWorks start only after CPU reset.

What prevents loading vxWorks in CPU?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Generally VxWorks 6.x BSPs are not designed to work with U-Boot. You may encounter random crash using the U-Boot **go/bootelf/bootvx** command after loading the VxWorks kernel. The reasons behind this might be different, for example it might be due to disagreement with the physical memory address configured in U-Boot, or inconsistent cache/MMU state.

The latest VxWorks 7 supports U-Boot as the bootloader by default on ARM and PPC targets.
Patches are now in the mainstream of the U-Boot Git repo since U-Boot v2014.01 relesae.

Answer (score 0):

There may be bootable and loadable vxworks images. You are probably run loadable image. That is the default option to build vxworks in workbench. That image expects some initialization to be done by bootloader (which is bootable vxworks that runs the "boottask", which in turn loads the vxworks image).

In short, try to build bootable/romable vxworks image and to load it. Otherwise load the bootloader (bootrom) image which will load your loadable vxworks image.